# Word Cloud MatplotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

Hello every one i am facing a issue and i found every where but no solution found yet.

The problem is i am creating a word cloud in which multiple language text exist like English, Urdu, Arabic,Chinese, Russian and else,

when i implement Bidi Algo in it and use the chinese font so it will work for all languages except Urdu, Arabic, Hindi etc. It works for russian, Chinese, English etc.

But when i use arabic reshaper it is not working and when i use Arabic reshaper with arial font then it only work for Arabic, Urdu, English.

Can we use multiple font in Word Cloud like chinese and arial both ?

or

Is there any another solution which will implement on all languages ?

Thanks